# BigInt calculations on the GPU in Julia

Tags: julia, biginteger

I need to perform calculations on random batches of very larger integers. I have a function that compares the numbers for certain properties and returns a value based on those properties. Since the batches and the numbers themselves can be very large I want to speed up the process by utilizing the GPU.
Here is a short version of what i have running purely on the CPU now.

```
using Statistics

function check(M)
    val = 0
    #some code that calculates val based on M, e.g. the mean
    val = mean(M) 
    return val
end

function distribution(N, n, exp) # N=batchsize, n=# of batches, exp=exponent of the upper limit of the integers
    avg = 0
    M = zeros(BigInt, N)
    for i = 1 : n
        M = rand(1 : BigInt(10) ^ exp, N)
        avg += check(M)
    end
    avg /= n
    println(avg, ":", N)
end

#example
distribution(10 ^ 3, 10 ^ 6, 100)
```

I have briefly used CUDAnative in Julia but I don't know how to implement the BigInt calculations. That package would be preferred but others are fine as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This likely will not work. bigint calculations require allocation, which really mess up gpu code. How big are the numbers you need? Could you use Floats? You might be able to use `Int128`s

Comment: There really us no upper limit on the size of the numbers. I ran it from 10^3 to 10^100. I know that allocation is always messy on the GPU when using exotic datatypes but as long as you overallocate it should be fine shouldnt it? And floats are not an option.

Answer (score 1):

`BigInt`s are CPU only since they are not implemented in Julia, see [1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic-1).